# Display Issues in KDE on laptop at startup (it happens when I plug and unplug the AC adapter)

Tags: linux, display

I have a display problem in KDE, sometimes at startup everything goes black except the mouse. 
It only happens in the Login screen or in the boot screen. Lilo displays correctly and once I have loaded KDE there is no problem.

I think it happens because Linux detects something else as a secondary monitor.
Also I have noticed that this happens only when I Shutdown the computer with the AC adapter unplugged and I turn on with the adapter plugged.

My Laptop is Toshiba and my Os is Linux Slackware 14.

Any hint is helpful, for example how can I diagnose by myself the exact problem.

Thanks

Comment: Does everything go black, or does the machine hang (check if CapsLock toggles the LED)? Do you have everything up to date (particularly kernel, X stuff)? What graphics card, which driver?

Comment: When it happens the screen goes black (not completely black as it were off) but I can see the mouse pointer. Also if I move the mouse around I can see it changing to the select text pointer when it moves over the place where the login form is supposed to be. Also I can log in perfectly although I cant see what is happening I hear the login sound.